# Box around SVG has wrong aspect ratio

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to line up placeholder SVGs over images of varying sizes. Everything works great *except* the box around SVG does not honor aspect ratio of the image. The SVG itself honors aspect ratio, but the box around it doesn't.

```
<img src="https://svgur.com/i/E06.svg" />

img {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 94%;
  max-width: 90%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 1vw 1vh 5vh 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

[JSfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/3c7j1u0w/1/)

It seems like the `height: 100%` and `max-height: 94%` together cause the SVG's box to always have 94% height. If I remove `height`, then I just get a tiny SVG that doesn't scale like I want. I haven't found any way to make the SVG's box behave the same way as the contents of the SVG behave, with regards to scaling and aspect ratio in the example.

Answer (score 0):

put the 
width :100%;
height :100%;
remove the max height and max width